# How can I access for System.PullRequest.TargetBranch predefined variable from Android's build.gradle file

Tags: android, azure, gradle

I have a project working with Azure Pipelines. On my builds I try to get some of the predefined variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

I'm able to access to `Build.BuildId`variable but not `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` variable. The code looks like this:

```
String getBuildId(){
    return System.getenv("BUILD_BUILDID") as String ?: "unknown"
}
String getTargetBranch(){
    return System.getenv("SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_TARGETBRANCH") as String ?: "unknown"
}

android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        getBuildId()
        getTargetBranch()
        ...
```

`getBuildId()` returns a number, however
`getTargetBranch()` always returns `unkown`

So how can I access for System.PullRequest.TargetBranch predefined variable from Android's build.gradle file?